# Having issues with outputting 3x3 blocks of "#"

Tags: c, for-loop, text

For one of my assignments in c, we are required to get a number of 3x3 squares of hashtags to print out.

So far I've been able to print out as many as i want horizontally with one space between each block, but I cannot have more than 5 to a row. Here is my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int i;
int limit;
int fives;
printf("Enter your desired number of squares...");
scanf("%d", &limit);
fives = limit/5;
for(i=0; i<limit; i++){
    printf("### ");    
}
printf("\n");
for(i=0; i<limit; i++){
    printf("### ");
}
printf("\n");
for(i=0; i<limit; i++){
    printf("### ");
}
printf("\n");

return 0;
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use the variable `fives` to detect when the user enters a number that's too high.  I would change the that line to: `limit = (limit >5) ? 5 : limit;`

Comment: So, you want to be able to input any number and that should produce that number*number matrix right? Can you show what your expected output is for certain numbers